# Image Processing. Finding center of objects

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am beginner of MAT LAB. I am trying to find the center point of object in an image, where object refers to a circle, square, star, triangle and pentagon. Can anyone help me or guide me in coding to find the center of above mentioned objects in an image?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25157-image-segmentation-tutorial-blobsdemo) is an Example thats uses `regionprops` as suggested by @Shai

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function `regionprops` that measures the properties of regions inside an image, for example: the area, the perimeter of a region, the centroid ...

I advice you to check the first example in this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) : *Calculate Centroids and Superimpose Locations on Image*. The code shows how to compute the centroids of different regions (letters) of a image containing text.

```
% read image text.png
BW = imread('text.png');

%Calculate centroids for connected components in the image using regionprops.
s = regionprops(BW,'centroid');

%Concatenate structure array containing centroids into a single matrix.
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);

% Display binary image with centroid locations superimposed.
imshow(BW)
hold on
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2), 'b*')
hold off
```